# Markov process states adding.

Tags: markov-process

I got a question from my exam paper. In its third (c) question the transition lime and orange is combined to a single drink called Li-Ora. How can I add the transition probabilities in this case? Will they change. Below I have attached the question. 
[image]

Will the answer be like this? [image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes. ${}$ ${}$ ${}$ ${}$ ${}$ ${}$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Fantini "This does not provide an answer to the question" Mwahahaa....